# ExtJS charts and graph

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My client has an existing application that uses fusion charts. Now we are recreating that application in ExtJS. My first question is how can I use 3D charts in ExtJS? Is there any plugin available to create 3D graphs for ExtJS? My second question is I want to use maps in ExtJS. The data shown in the charts has to be displayed geographically. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the charting that comes stock with Ext JS? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/charts/Area.html

While not "3D", they are very robust and can create some very complex data visualizations.

Regarding the maps/charts integration, that should be quite simple. You could simply detect the click even for a particular geographical data point on the map, and load store data for that which in turn could generate the appropriate chart data. Although it's not geographic specific, you might check out this example for some inspiration: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/charts/FormDashboard.html

Comment: Thanks for your views but the client is quite clear on the requirement of "3D" charts. I personally like ExtJS charts very much but I have to look towards alternatives. Maybe integrating fusion charts with ExtJS :)

Comment: You could always extend the Ext JS charting and make them "3D". All of the tools are there.